# Finding the source of events in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

In the last month, I started noticing around 50 new event types that started recording.  I did not add these in GTM or as custom dimensions or audiences.  Some will record 100s of event occurrences per day with names like "Create Report Viz", "Resize pancake", "Add New Component".  How do I find where these are firing to stop them?